# How to get byte data from audio file (must be as signed int / bytes) in Flutter/Dart like AudioInputStream gives you in java

Tags: java, flutter, dart

Good day. I'm trying to create a music identification app (like Shazam) in Flutter (I'm also new to Flutter) and I want it to run on mobile and desktop.

I have this piece of code **in Java** that gives me back a byte array with the time domain values in it :

```java
File soundFile;
AudioInputStream audioStream;
AudioFormat audioFormat;
SourceDataLine sourceLine;
int check = 0;
byte[] songBytes;
DataLine.Info info;

soundFile = new File("./testWave.wav");
songBytes = new byte[(int) soundFile.length()];
audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
audioFormat = audioStream.getFormat();
info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
sourceLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
sourceLine.open(audioFormat);
sourceLine.start();
while (check > -1) {
    check = audioStream.read(songBytes, 0, songBytes.length);
}
sourceLine.drain();
sourceLine.close();
for (int i = 0; i < songBytes.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(songBytes[i]);
}
```

I have searched and could not find any way to do this in Flutter/Dart. Can anyone please give me guidance on whats the best way of doing this in Flutter/Dart if it is possible and if not can you please advise me on the best method of doing this

Comment: Presumably, your WAV is in a normal format like mono, PCM shorts or floats. It will have a header with blocks - typically `fmt `, `fact` and `data`. The first two describe the format - sample rate, number of channels, bits per sample, etc and the third contains a contiguous block of bytes in that format (for example little-endian 16 bit shorts). It's a bit more work than Java, but you really just need to strip off the header up to and included the `data` block header then interpret the rest of the buffer as shorts - for example, using `ByteData.buffer.asInt16List()`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I get the logic your presenting I'm just not sure how I would get the ByteData into the buffer. What library or functions should I use cause I want to get the data from files that maybe in any directory. I've seen rootBundle.load(audioAssetsFullPath) which loads them from the assets. It returns the wanted data I believe but I dont believe it can load the data from any directory

Comment: Use `File.readAsBytes` to read from an arbitrary file in a directory.

Comment: that would return me an Uint8List which wouldn't bring me back negative or does it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say your WAV header is 74 bytes long. (It will vary according to the number of sections, so really you need to parse it to determine that. But for any one source of WAV files it will often be the same number - use a hex dump to determine the offset of the `data` block plus 4.)

(By parsing the header you can find out other things like the sample rate and whether it's mono or stereo, etc.)

Then, if `bytes` is the `Uint8List`, you need `bytes.buffer.asInt16List(74)`. This means: interpret the buffer backing the bytes as signed shorts, but starting at offset 74 - after the header.

```
  var dataOffset = 74; // parse the WAV header or determine from a hex dump
  var bytes = await file.readAsBytes();
  var shorts = bytes.buffer.asInt16List(dataOffset);
  print(shorts[0]); // the first sample of audio
  print(shorts.length); // the number of audio samples
```